# HTTP v Socket v RMI chat in Java

Tags: java, http, sockets, chat, rmi

I am trying to integrate a chat servlet with my JSP pages. I need to decide on whether to use HTTP v Socket v RMI for the chat communication?
I have a few questions 1. Which of these protocols are most open (i.e. least restricted by firewalls, blocked ports, anti virus/spam blocks) 2. Which of these offer better performance? 3. Are there any browser restrictions ( I need to use the chat functionality on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.

Help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of writing an Applet or using AJAX?

Comment: Question could be dumb, but can my JSP communicate directly with the servlet (instead of an applet or AJAX)?

Comment: No real reason, AJAX/Applet will give better real time communication though, otherwise you'll end up having to pool the Servlet for new messages

Answer (score 0):

> Which of these protocols are most open (i.e. least restricted by firewalls, blocked ports, anti virus/spam blocks)

HTTP for sure.

> Which of these offer better performance?

Hard to say.  In practice, I think it depends more on the implementation than on the protocol itself.

> Are there any browser restrictions ( I need to use the chat functionality on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.

I suspect that there aren't browser-specific restrictions.  However, if you are running an untrusted applet, the Java security sandbox is going to block a lot of things, including the hosts that the applet can connect to over the network.  For details on what an untrusted applet can / cannot do, read this:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html